# printing output as a table in python terminal and saving output as a .txt with proper headings

Tags: python-2.7, output

I have written a code to find approximated sum of an exponential function, which should run iteration till N-1 terms, then return the iteration no, sum, abs error and relative error for each iteration step.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

N = input ("Please enter an integer at which term you want to turncate your summation")
x = input ("please enter a number for which you want to run the exponential summation e^{x}")


function= math.exp(x)
exp_sum = 0.0
abs_err = 0.0
rel_err = 0.0


for n in range (0, N):
    factorial = math.factorial(n)
    power     = x**n
    nth_term  = power/factorial
    exp_sum   = exp_sum + nth_term
    abs_err   = abs(function - exp_sum)
    rel_err   = abs(abs_err)/abs(function)


    print "The exponential function which has %d-term expansion, returns the approximated sum to be %.16f." % (n, exp_sum)
    print "This approximated sum has an absolute error to be %.25f" % abs_err
    print "and a relative error to be %.25f" % rel_err
```

right now, it actually looks silly printing values at each iteration and it only looks good till a few iteration, my plan is to get the output as a   table with proper column headings (iteration, sum, abs err, rel err) in the terminal after I execute the .py file.

also I wish to save a .txt file of the output, if anyone has idea how to do that in python, I would very much appreciate the help and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a `pretty_table()` function in order to pretty print tabular data, like this:

```
def pretty_table(rows, column_count, column_spacing=4):
    aligned_columns = []
    for column in range(column_count):
        column_data = list(map(lambda row: row[column], rows))
        aligned_columns.append((max(map(len, column_data)) + column_spacing, column_data))

    for row in range(len(rows)):
        aligned_row = map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][row]), aligned_columns)
        yield ''.join(map(lambda x: x[1] + ' ' * (x[0] - len(x[1])), aligned_row))
```

This little function, given a list of rows and the number of columns, will yield pretty-formatted table data, line by line. You can even adjust the spacing between columns if you wish.

In your particular code, you may do the following:

```
# At first, contains just the header columns.
rows = [['Term', 'Exponential sum', 'Absolute error', 'Relative error']]
for n in range (0, N):
    factorial = math.factorial(n)
    power     = x**n
    nth_term  = power/factorial
    exp_sum   = exp_sum + nth_term
    abs_err   = abs(function - exp_sum)
    rel_err   = abs(abs_err)/abs(function)

    rows.append((str(n), str(exp_sum), str(abs_err), str(rel_err)))

for line in pretty_table(rows, 4):
    print(line)
```

For an input of `N = 10, X = 5`, this code outputs:

```
Term    Exponential sum    Absolute error    Relative error     
0       1.0                147.413159103     0.993262053001     
1       6.0                142.413159103     0.959572318005     
2       18.5               129.913159103     0.875347980517     
3       39.3333333333      109.079825769     0.734974084703     
4       65.375             83.0381591026     0.559506714935     
5       91.4166666667      56.9964924359     0.384039345167     
6       113.118055556      35.295103547      0.237816537027     
7       128.619047619      19.7941114835     0.13337167407      
8       138.307167659      10.1059914438     0.0680936347218    
9       143.68945657       4.72370253291     0.0318280573062
```

If you want to redirect it into a file, do this instead of the last `for` loop:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in pretty_table(rows, 4):
        print >> output, line
```